# Inner StackPanel isn't visible

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have one `StackPanel` inside another with a couple of labels inside the inner `StackPanel`. For some reason the the inner `StackPanel` and the `Label`s are not displaying at all, why is this?

```
<Window x:Class="WeatherApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Weather Application" Height="550" Width="850" Loaded="Window_Loaded" IsEnabled="True" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Icon="/WeatherApplication;component/Images/weatherIcon.png">
    <Grid Height="522" Background="#FFE7E7E7">
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="35" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial">
                <MenuItem Header="_File" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="7,8,8,3">
                    <MenuItem Header="_Settings"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Help" Padding="7,8,8,3">
                    <MenuItem Header="_Guide"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="_About"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <Menu.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WeatherApplication;component/Images/menuBG.png" />
                </Menu.Background>
            </Menu>
            <StackPanel Width="230" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin=" 5">
                <Label Content="Search location" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" Height="28" Name="searchLocationLabel" IsEnabled="False" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="100" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" Margin="3">Town</Label>
                    <TextBox Margin="3" Width="120"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="100" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" Margin="3">County</Label>
                    <TextBox Margin="3" Width="120"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="100" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" Margin="3">Post Code</Label>
                    <TextBox Margin="3" Width="120"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Search" Height="23" Name="searchButton" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 5"/>
                <Separator Height="5" Name="separator1" Width="245" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                <Label Content="Weather Today" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" Height="28" Name="weatherTodayLabel" IsEnabled="False" Margin="0 5"/>
                <Label Content="Bury St Edmunds" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="28" Name="label1" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="110" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Temperature:"></Label>
                    <Label Width="130" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="75&#176;"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="110" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Condition:"></Label>
                    <Label Width="130" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Mostly Cloudy"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="110" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Hi:"></Label>
                    <Label Width="130" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="75&#176;"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="110" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Low:"></Label>
                    <Label Width="130" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="75&#176;"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="110" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Wind Speed:"></Label>
                    <Label Width="130" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="12mph"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="110" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Humidity:"></Label>
                    <Label Width="130" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="75&#176;"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="110" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Sunrise:"></Label>
                    <Label Width="130" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="11:40am"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="110" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Sunset:"></Label>
                    <Label Width="130" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="4:41pm"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Width="580" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="right" Background="#FFD14040" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30 -10 -1 0" ZIndex="-1">
                    <Border Width="575" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="right" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0 0 -0 0">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="10"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                    </Border>

            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="stackPanel111" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Height="100" Background="AliceBlue">
                    <Label Width="110" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Tuesday" />
                    <Label Width="130" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="75&#176;" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I copied you xaml and pasted into my project, and both lables are visible.

Comment: They are, but off-screen.

Comment: Remove Height and Width of the top Stackpanel and see if this is your desired layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Width="580"` in your first stack panel conflicts with the `Width="525"` of the `Window`. It pushes the content off-screen.

Remove the `StackPanel`'s `Width`, and you will be fine:

```
<StackPanel Name="stackPanel111" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel Height="100" Background="AliceBlue">
        <Label Width="110" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Tuesday" />
        <Label Width="130" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Content="75&#176;" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Running this in an empty application, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: That didn't help. I added a screen shot of UI with you're markup. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Well it kind of is, but isn't. Notice the AliceBlue background of the inner StackPanel isn't shown. Nor is the content of each label!

Comment: @crm: See the update how it looks in an empty application `Window`. Let me know if it works for you too.

Comment: It didn't change anything. I added the rest of the xaml. Perhaps something else is causing issues?

Comment: All the other panels have heights too. I guess they are conflicting. Can we agree this fixes the first issue?

Comment: Sure, although it was never pushed off the screen to start with. That wasn't ever the issue. Just that the contents aren't visible.